# Accessing subdirectory module in django

Tags: python, django

I have a very simple Django application I'm starting. I've run through the tutorial on djangoproject.com and got it working, now I'm building my site. However, I'm having trouble getting my url routing to work. My directory structure is

```
/dartagnan
--/menu
   __init__.py
   admin.py
   models.py
   urls.py
   views.py
__init__.py
settings.py
urls.py
```

My models are working, and I have (had) the admin up and running. I added the menu/urls with

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from dartagnan.menu import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

My installed apps includes bot 'dartagnan' and 'dartagnan.menu'

and I updated the top level urls.py to have

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^menu/', include('menu.urls')),
)
```

Now when I try to visit, say localhost/menu I get the error:

```
ImportError at /menu
No module named menu.urls
```

I've tried 'dartagnan.menu.urls', and a bunch of other variations. I've tried to find a similar question to learn from, but if someone is having the same problem I'm too new at python and django to realize they are the same.

Edit: per request, the error trace

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/menu

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'dartagnan',
 'dartagnan.menu')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  88.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  71.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  596.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  476.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  337.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  365.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  360.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/Users/Christopher/Sourcecode/dartagnan/dartagnan/urls.py" in <module>
  19.         url(r'^menu/', include('menu.urls')),
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/Users/Christopher/dartagnan-base-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /menu
Exception Value: No module named menu.urls
```

Comment: can you show the full stack trace. the code above appears correct.

Comment: In your top urls use 'dartagan.menu.urls' instead of 'menu.urls' and then show us the stack trace again. And remove 'dartagnan' from INSTALLED_APPS, its worthless.

Comment: So when I did that, everything worked. If you want to put that down below as an answer, I'll gladly accept it so that if anyone else stumbles on this question they will know what to do.